# ¿Como puedo validar que cuando se registre un usuario no repita el nombre del otro usuario? en ruby on rails y devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

La idea es que cuando un usuario se registre no repite el nombre de un usuario que ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos por otro usuario.
Que si hay usuario registrado le salga error USUARIO YA REGISTRADO

Comment: Prueba con la validación [`uniqueness`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) en tu modelo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como comenta [Alter Lagos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/213/alter-lagos)

En tu modelo de usuario, por ejemplo en `user.rb`, agrega esta sentencia

`validates_uniqueness_of :name`

En caso que necesites que la validación no sea susceptible a mayúsculas y minúsculas la validación quedará:

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, case_sensitive: false`

Comment: Y como podria traducir el mensaje que saldria en devise.es.yml ?